# Equivalent of NCrunch for Java in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, tdd, ncrunch

I'm looking for a tool that does continuous testing while I'm writing code (such as NCrunch for Visual Studio) for Java in Eclipse. Is there something like that available for free?

Ideally, it would test continuously, but also give me a feedback in real time of which lines pass and which don't.

Comment: here's another one: http://code.google.com/p/t2framework/

Comment: t2framework now leads to https://git.science.uu.nl/prase101/t3/wikis/home when I followed the links/redirects.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know NCrunch. But [Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.com/) is a nice continuous test runner for Eclipse (probably with less features than NCrunch). It runs unit tests affected by changed code on every save action and displays the results in the status bar.

However, it only works for "plain" JUnit tests, not for plugin based JUnit tests (i.e. you cannot use it when developing Eclipse plugins yourself).

Comment: Indeed it has less features than nCrunch but it definitely works well! I'm still doing tests with it, thanks for your input.

Comment: The URL is now https://infinitest.github.io/